# Inject specific beans as parameters in function with multiple parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I understand that i can use @Autowired to inject a bean in a class.

Now i get curious::
I don't want to have a private attribute with @Autowired.
I have a function in my controller and i want to inject bean  as parameters directely in the function.
I got an error saying that file and token are not beans.

Is there a way to autowire or inject just the beans i need as parameters ?

```
@Controller
public class SpinalToolboxWebController {

    /*@Autowired
    private FileOperationsService fileOperationsService;


    @Autowired
    private Comparator<String> comparator;

    @Autowired
    private ServerResponse serverResponse;

    @Autowired
    private SoftwareCommunicationService softwareCommunicationService;

    @Autowired
    private StringBuffer stringBuffer;

    @Autowired
    private UserEnvironmentService userEnvironmentService;*/


    @Autowired
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    public  @ResponseBody
    ServerResponse handleUploadedFiles(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
                                       @RequestParam(value="token") String token, 
                                       SoftwareCommunicationService softwareCommunicationService,
                                       FileOperationsService fileOperationsService, 
                                       ServerResponse serverResponse )throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Passing throught upload controller");

        if(!fileOperationsService.isUploadedFileExtensionAllowed(file.getOriginalFilename()))
        {
            serverResponse.setUndefinedResponse();
            return serverResponse;
        }

        if(fileOperationsService.uploadFile(file, token)){
            serverResponse.setResponse(file, softwareCommunicationService.generateRawAndHeader(file));
        }
        else{
            serverResponse.setUndefinedResponse();
        }
        return serverResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you want fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a built-in feature, no. You can't do what you are suggesting.

Spring, however, provides the tools to program this functionality yourself. You'll need to come up with a marker annotation type. Something like `@MethodBean`. You can annotate the handler method parameters you want injected from the `ApplicationContext`. You'll then need to write a class that extends `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and which looks for this annotation. You have to add an `@Autowired` `WebApplicationContext` field from which to get the beans and supply them to the method.

You'd then register this bean as part of the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s of our MVC stack.

When Spring determines that it has to invoke the handler method in your example, which now looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody
ServerResponse handleUploadedFiles(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
                                   @RequestParam(value="token") String token, 
                                   @MethodBean SoftwareCommunicationService softwareCommunicationService,
                                   @MethodBean FileOperationsService fileOperationsService, 
                                   @MethodBean ServerResponse serverResponse )throws IOException {
```

it will use the appropriate `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve an argument for each of the parameters.

For the `@MethodBean` annotated parameters, it will find your custom implementation, look for a bean of the type of the parameter in the injected `WebApplicationContext`, and provide it as an argument.

Comment: thanks for your nice explanation. the reason i thought about this is that since my controller is a singleton, if i use "at Autowired private ServerResponse serverResponse" for example, and then use serverResponse in the method,  is there a risk that a user access another one 's data?

Comment: @bigjel That depends on what `ServerResponse` is. Did you mean `ServletResponse`? If yes, then there is no issue. Spring will do some intelligent processing which will make it so that your controller only see the `ServletResponse` it's currently working with.

Comment: No it's a class that i created for the server response. its contains private String fields ... and get/set methods.

Comment: @bigjel Are you going to make a bean out of it? Will it be request-scoped or singleton-scoped? Those are the questions you should answer when thinking about concurrency issues.

Comment: yes, ServerResponse is request scoped bean. is there a chance that user2  gets user1's server response since the controller (singleton). here is the Server Reponse in detail: https://github.com/neuropoly/spinalcordtoolbox_web/blob/master/src/main/java/spinalToolBoxWeb/fileOperations/model/ServerResponse.java

Comment: @bigjel No, there is no such possibility while using `@Autowired`.

Comment: so when the second user comes, the controller will autowire with that user request beans? i am right?

Comment: @bigjel Yes, one request - one request-scoped bean. If you use an `@Autowired` field, Spring injects a **Proxy** which knows how to retrieve the request-scoped bean.